# TestComplete 10 Inconsistant Error on Object

Tags: testcomplete

We have a huge number of test running against our web application and i have come across a very strange error.

We have a function that will upload a file into the application, within this it will click the browse button, input a location and click ok followed by upload.

This works on 90% of the tests and its the same function being called into all the seperate scripts, but in some tests its failing because its unable to locate the object (in this case the browse button on the dialog box)

Its being tested on the multiple machines, its the same target server we are testing against, its the same IE version but we care getting a different results and im running out of ideas.

although when you map the object in TestComplete and compare this against what the test is looking for, they are identical.

**Mapped Object using the object spy**
Aliases.browser.pageModspace.panelMangoentryformC.panelMangoentryformAddFile.panelBd.panelEntryformcontent.panelModspacedialog.formEntryform.tableFilesourceTable.cellFilesourceOptionFile.fileFilesourceinputfield

**The object it failed to find**
Aliases.browser.pageModspace.panelMangoentryformC.panelMangoentryformAddFile.panelBd.panelEntryformcontent.panelModspacedialog.formEntryform.tableFilesourceTable.cellFilesourceOptionFile.fileFilesourceinputfield

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load of objects can take different time on different computers. You can try the following:

1. Modify your test to get the problematic object via the WaitAliasChild method. In this case, TestComplete will wait for an object during the specified time:

   *Aliases.browser.pageModspace.panelMangoentryformC.panelMangoentryformAddFile.
   panelBd.panelEntryformcontent.panelModspacedialog.formEntryform.tableFilesourceTable.
   cellFilesourceOptionFile.**WaitAliasChild(“fileFilesourceinputfield”, 20000)***

Details: http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/55413/

2. Increase the **Auto-wait timeout** project option. This will make TestComplete wait for objects longer. However, you need to use this option very carefully as it can affect the total time execution. Details: http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/55316/